# Swap two workspaces

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments, workspaces

I have several workspaces active in Ubuntu 22.04. Is it possible to re arrange them? E.g. suppose I start in this condition:

```
A | B | C
```

and I want to go to this condition:

```
A | C | B
```

Is it possible to do this easily? I tried click and drag but it moves windows rather than whole workspaces.

Note that what I want to do is to interchange two workspaces, not to move from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to swap workspaces in Ubuntu 22.04. To do this, first open the Activities Overview by pressing the Super key. This will show all the available workspaces and their respective windows. Now drag one of the workspaces to the left or to the right. This will swap the two workspaces. You can also use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Arrow to switch between the workspaces.

Comment: Note that what I want to do is to interchange two workspaces, not to move from one to the other.